# Change background color for different slides

Tags: impress.js

I am trying impress.js out but I wonder i there is a way to change the background color of the body for some slides. I would like my first 3 slides to have a different background then the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike reveal.js perhaps,it is not possible,

You can use jimpress http://jmpressjs.github.com/jmpress.js/#/home

here is a demo in which background changes

http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/SlideshowJmpress/

customize it as per your requirements so as to remove the slide structure

Answer (score 8):

You do not have to resort to javascript to alter the background-color 
of the `body` tag when a particular slide is in focus.

For each slide you make, impress.js requires you to give the slide an `id`;
impress.js then takes the `id` and adds it to the `body` tag 
as part of a "built on the fly" class name.

So suppose you have three slides:

```
<div id="impress">   
  <div id="first" class="step slide"  data-x="-1500" data-y="1200" data-transition-duration="2000">
    <p>First</p>
  </div>    
  <div id="second" class="step slide"  data-x="0" data-y="1200" data-transition-duration="2000">
    <p>Second</p>
  </div>    
  <div id="third" class="step slide"  data-x="1500" data-y="1200" data-transition-duration="3000">
    <p>Third</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, if you use the DOM inspector in your modern browser, 
you will see impress.js alter one of the css classes on the `body`
tag as each slide becomes "live", giving you these classes to work with:

- `.impress-on-first`
- `.impress-on-second`
- `.impress-on-third`

...where **impress-on-** is the beginning, and your **slide id** is the end of the class name.

Using this hook impress.js gives you, you can set the css properties of 
the `body` tag for each slide.

```
/* add css3 transition properties for smooth transitions */
.impress-on-first {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: #000;
}

.impress-on-second {
    background-color: orange;
    color: #fff;
}

.impress-on-third {
    background-color: red;
    color: #fff;
}
```

**Demonstration**
Working demo here in jsbin:
https://jsbin.com/dotudelaco/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 2):

I have a slightly different approach... if you aren't afraid of a bit of jquery! Using the jquery colour plugin - (https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) you can do the following:

```
// keep a list of slide ids and desired background colours
var bgs = {
    "main": "#FFF",
    "other": "#000"
};

// use the 'stepenter' event (step leave is better but requires 
//a modification to impress, more on this below)
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('impress:stepenter', function(e) {
        var slide = $(e.target).attr("id");

        // the jquery-colour plugin allows animating background colours here
        $("body").animate({
            backgroundColor: bgs[slide]
        }, 500 );
    });
});
```

In the comments, I mention `stepleave` as a better solution as it can be used to transition the background colour as you switch between slides.  However `stepleave` doesn't expose the nextSlide yet.

If you are game to modify the impress core, then this [pull request](https://github.com/bartaz/impress.js/pull/206) is a good place to start!

Answer (score 0):

Please check this example http://franciscomurillo.com/fio/#/credits  you need to get the active step from the events, and change the background by yourself like this:

```
<script>
var api = impress();
api.init();

//Here you can show any background for current slide/step.
window.addEventListener('impress:stepenter', function(event) {
    console.log(":::   " + event.target.id);

    if (event.target.id == "credits") {
        console.log("In credits step");
        $("#mc_wallpaper").removeClass("fade-out");
        $("#mc_wallpaper").addClass("fade-in");

    }



}, false);


//Here you can hide any background you showed for current slide/step.
window.addEventListener('impress:stepleave', function(event) {
    console.log("impress:stepleave ");
    if (event.target.id == "credits") {
        console.log("Out of :: credits");
        $("#mc_wallpaper").addClass("fade-out");
        $("#mc_wallpaper").removeClass("fade-in");

    }
}, false);

</script>
```

Then I have this css code in style.css:

```
/* make keyframes that tell the start state and the end state of our object */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }

.fade-in {
    opacity:0;  /* make things invisible upon start */
    -webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;  /* call our keyframe named fadeIn, use animattion ease-in and repeat it only 1 time */
    -moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
    animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;

    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;  /* this makes sure that after animation is done we remain at the last keyframe value (opacity: 1)*/
    -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;

    -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
    -moz-animation-duration:1s;
    animation-duration:1s;
}


/* make keyframes that tell the start state and the end state of our object */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut { from { opacity:1; } to { opacity:0; } }
@-moz-keyframes fadeOut { from { opacity:1; } to { opacity:0; } }
@keyframes fadeOut { from { opacity:1; } to { opacity:0; } }

.fade-out {
    opacity:0;  /* make things invisible upon start */
    -webkit-animation:fadeOut ease-in 1;  /* call our keyframe named fadeOut, use animattion ease-in and repeat it only 1 time */
    -moz-animation:fadeOut ease-in 1;
    animation:fadeOut ease-in 1;

    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;  /* this makes sure that after animation is done we remain at the last keyframe value (opacity: 1)*/
    -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;

    -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
    -moz-animation-duration:1s;
    animation-duration:1s;
}


#mc_wallpaper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff url(../images/vUYioU8.jpg) no-repeat center center / cover;
    opacity: 0;

}
```

and finally the div element in your index.html

```
<div id="mc_wallpaper"> </div>
```

This is not only useful for color but for any background you want.
I hope this helps!

Cheers!